# How to read files in a .zip file in Java?

Tags: java, zip, extract

I would like to parse a .zip file. The .zip file contains one folder. The folder in turn contains several files. I would like to read all files without writing the .zip file to disk. I have the following code:

```
        zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

        while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(reader);
            inputStream.nextLine();

            while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
                String data = inputStream.nextLine(); // Gets a whole line
                String[] line = data.split(SEPARATOR); // Splits the line up into a string array
            }

            inputStream.close();
            stream.close();
        }
        zipFile.close();
```

The problem is that this only works when the files are directly in the .zip file. How can I adapt my code so that it also works when the files are inside a folder in the .zip file?

Comment: use entry.isDirectory()... 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#isDirectory()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the code that reads content inside an `if`

```
ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
    InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
...
    stream.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will skip the directory but the actual files are inside this directory, that means I have to go inside the directory. So my .zip file contains a folder named "x". Inside this folder there are files x/file1,csv, x/file2.csv. How can I then read this files?

Comment: But it **does** iterate through the entries inside the directory.

Comment: Oh, I have to check it.