# How to read content from a text zip file?

Tags: java

This prints everything one one line. My original text file has different lines. How to still get the content line by line after the file is zipped? I am working on Mac.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    QuickTest mfe = new QuickTest();
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("test.txt.zip");

    for (Enumeration e = zip.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
        System.out.println(entry.getName());
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            if (FilenameUtils.getExtension(entry.getName()).equals("txt")) {
                StringBuilder out = getTxtFiles(zip.getInputStream(entry));
                System.out.println(out.toString());
            }
        }
    }


    System.out.println("Done");
}

private  static StringBuilder getTxtFiles(InputStream in)  {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // do something, probably not a text file
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Is the text file originally from a Mac?  What end of line marker do you use in the text file?

Comment: Yes, it's on Mac. I don't know the marker. It's a regular text file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read files in a .zip file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313884/how-to-read-files-in-a-zip-file-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your method:

```
private  static StringBuilder getTxtFiles(InputStream in)  {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line;
```

The following loop:

```
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
        }
```

reads lines but the Java `readLine()` method does not append an end-of-line character.  You'll need to add a newline (or carriage return for the Mac) to see lines.

```
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
            out.append( '\n' );
        }
```